# How to use 'includefoot' of 'geometry' only on 'plain.scrheadings' pages and not 'scrheadings' pages?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script, geometry

I have the following layout:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[left=1.9cm, right=1.9cm, bottom=2.23cm, top=2.23cm]{geometry}% specific requirements
\usepackage[markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lohead{\headmark}
\rohead{\pagemark}
\lehead{\pagemark}
\rehead{\headmark}
\rofoot[\pagemark]{}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[18]
\end{document}
```

On pages which start with a new chapter (like page 1 in the MWE above), I
would like the space between the bottom of the page and the page number to
be the same (2.23cm) than the space between the bottom of the page and the
text on pages other than those on which a new chapter starts (like page 2 in
the MWE). If I use the `includefoot` setting of `geometry`, then the space
is adjusted on all pages, not just those with a page number at the bottom...

So, in essence, what I need is something like `includefoot` but which is
only active on `plain.scrheadings` pages (new chapter starts) and not on
`scrheadings` pages (other pages). If there is a better way than working
with geometry, that's fine, but I have to use these exact margins and also
the headings (page number at bottom on pages where chapter starts and
otherwise in the header).

Comment: Sounds odd to have a different \textheight on chapter pages, but if you need it, you should use \enlargethispage{whatever} on such pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten `\textheight` on chapter pages you can use `\enlargethispage` as suggested by @Ulrike Fischer in a comment. Therefore you can patch `\chapterlinesformat`.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\chapterlinesformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\chapterlineswithprefixformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

With the patch of `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` it would also work if you add class option `chapterprefix` or `appendixprefix` etc.

To shift the page number on plain pages, you can shift all footer layers of page style `plain`:

```
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot}
    {\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-\footskip]{#1}}
    {}%
}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.9cm, vmargin=2.23cm% specific requirements
  , showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- sets style `scrheadings` automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% <- scrlayer-scrpage macro  
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot}
    {\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-\footskip]{#1}}
    {}%
}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\chapterlinesformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\chapterlineswithprefixformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[18]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But then the footer is shifted for all pages using `plain` style while text height changes only on chapter pages automatically.

So I would suggest to declare a new page style only for the chapter pages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.9cm, vmargin=2.23cm% specific requirements
  , showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=plain.scrheadings.foot.odd,
  addvoffset=-\footskip,
]{chapterpage.foot.odd}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{chapterpage}{chapterpage.foot.odd}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{chapterpage}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\chapterlinesformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\chapterlineswithprefixformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[18]
\end{document}
```

If other pages with style `plain` should not get the page number:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.9cm, vmargin=2.23cm% specific requirements
  , showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=plain.scrheadings.foot.odd,
  addvoffset=-\footskip,
  contents=\hfill\pagemark
]{chapterpage.foot.odd}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{chapterpage}{chapterpage.foot.odd}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{chapterpage}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\chapterlinesformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\chapterlineswithprefixformat
  {\enlargethispage{-\footskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\blindtext[18]
\end{document}
```

The results are the same as above.